# Is "Satguru" a standard Hindu honorific like "goswami","paramahamsa" etc.?

Tags: shiva

Is it a title given to Siva-worshipers like Sivaya Subramuniaswami and Jaggi Vasudev?

Comment: Here is a link that might shed an example: [What is a Satguru](https://youtu.be/54GH19i0B7Y)